# I can't import photos in GarageBand

Tags: macos, photos, garageband

Every website or video tutorial about adding artwork to my projects shows that the media browser has tabs/buttons for Audio, Photos, Movies.  My GarageBand has only Audio and Movies.

If I try to drag a photo in, it is just ignored.  I can drag movies or audio files in with no problem, but not photos.

How do I get a photo into my project?

Answer (score 1):

If your media browser in Garage Band is only showing tabs for Audio and Movies, this means the first time you tried to use the Media Browser you didn't give GarageBand permission to access your Photos.

In other words, you would have had a prompt such as:

[image]

As you can see from the image above, you can still provide access after initially denying access by:

1. Going to **Apple > System Preferences > Security & Privacy**
2. Select the **Privacy** tab
3. Select the **Photos** app from the list of apps on the left
4. You should now see something similar to:

[image]

5. Now tick the checkbox next to GarageBand
6. If GarageBand is running, you'll see a prompt asking you if you want to Quit GarageBand now or later - select **Quit Now**.

Once you launch GarageBand again you'll see that Photos are now available within your Media Browser.

Comment: thanks for this, but it didn't actually fix the problem.  GarageBand was already checked.  I also tried unchecking it (which prompted to quit GarageBand), re-opening GB, re-selecting GB in the privacy tab (again prompted to quit GB), and finally re-opening GB.  There was still no photos tab.

Comment: The Media Browser access the photo library used by the Photos app. Do you actually use the Photos app on your Mac?

Comment: I do have several photos and some slide shows in the photos app.